# Visual studio code vertical guidelines

Tags: visual-studio-code

One of my extensions in Visual studio code turned off default vertical guidelines and even if it seems trivial I can't find setting that may turn it on again.

How it works now:

[image: How it works now:]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result:]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the setting your are looking for is:

> Editor: **Render Indent Guides**

or through the settings file itsef:

`"editor.renderIndentGuides": true`

You can access the settings by pressing <kbd>CTRL/⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and then search for "render indent".